# count(*) on mysql giving me value 0

Tags: mysql, sql, count

```
select count(*)  FROM antecedente_delito WHERE rut_polichile = NEW.rut_polichile
```

this statement is giving de value 0, when it should give me 18 :/ ive been trying a lot to find any bug in it.

Comment: What is **NEW.rut_polichile** ?

Comment: this is a condition inside a trigger, that initializes after inserting on antecedente_delito which has the field: rut_polichile VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL

Comment: @Matias, es mejor si explicas qué es lo que queres lograr y muestras la estructura de tus tablas. Un saludo.

Comment: Can you show us the whole code for the trigger?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mjRSnJ9c

Comment: Are you certain that the insert succeeds and is not prevented by the referential integrity enforced on the columns?

Comment: It looks to me that there is an extra closing parenthesis `)` on each `IF` and `ELSEIF` line.

Comment: You should also change the order of comparison to largest to smallest.  Check for > 40 first, then > 30, then > 20, etc.  Otherwise since 29 (for example) > 10 it will be caught first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working solution that I mocked up using/changing your code in SqlFiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac2e9/1

Answer (score 0):

To trouble shoot this, I would view your actual values and verify that NEW. is returning what you think it should. Sometimes it may be doing some trims or removal of special characters, especially the _ and % signs are likely to stripped in subprocedures.

I would start with the query:

```
select top 50 rut_polichile, NEW.rut_plichile FROM antecedente_delito
```

If the issue is not obvious from that add in a varbinary check:

```
select top 50 cast( rut_polichile as varbinary), cast(NEW.rut_plichile as varbinary) from antecedente_delito
```

If the table only has 18 records, then you should be good to go with the above troubleshooting, but if there is more data, I would suggest limiting your results from the above by the rowid or other identifier in a where statement.

It's not the answer, but I hope it helps you find the answer.

Comment: If either of the statements is returning a NULL then an isnull(Value,"") should return everything.

Answer (score -1):

The SELECT privilege for the subject table if references to table columns occur via OLD.col_name or NEW.col_name in the trigger definition.

but in your trigger i can't see any trigger definition. so try without NEW.

for more info: http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysqldocs/v51/triggers.html or 
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31068